# d3.js zoom propagation in v4: pinch zooming a map when one finger is over a child element

Tags: javascript, android, ios, d3.js, touch

I have an interactive map with places of interest represented as svg circles. Each circle has a touchstart or mousedown event, and the transparent rectangle behind is bound to d3.zoom() so you can zoom in on the map! Here's the set up if you were to inspect the elements:

```
<div id="map">
    <svg>
        <g><rect></rect></g> <!-- transparent rect bound to d3.zoom() -->
        <g>
            <circle></circle> <!-- places of interest with touchstart listeners -->
            <circle></circle>
            ...
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Now if I pinch zoom, and one of my fat fingers happens to be on one of these circles, the zoom will behave strangely on my phone unless I prevent the zoom from occurring whenever a circle is touched like so:

```
  selection.append("circle").on("touchstart mousedown",function(d,i){
       d3.event.preventDefault(); // no zoom for you
       // ... code to highlight circle or whatever 
  }
```

This way, if the user accidentally zooms with one finger on a circle or place of interest, the circle highlights and the zoom is cancelled. Reading [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2887) discussion and also [issue 66](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/66) from the same discussion has aided me nicely in setting this up.

So zoom works, provided the user avoids places of interest when zooming.

**However**, what I'd really like to do is have this set up the other way around and have the zoom take first priority always.

I have tried placing the circles behind the zoom rectangle, but of course the circles no longer receive touch events. This is unfortunate because the map zooms perfectly when you can no longer interact with the places of interest.

I am getting by at the moment by making the places of interest smaller than I'd like, so I can increase the chances the user will zoom on the map only. This is of course sub-optimal.

One day perhaps I will gain an intuitive understanding of touch events, but for now I humbly ask how to approach this as I am getting lost. Any suggestions on how to prioritize zoom over touchstart for my map would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this got me my tumbleweed badge. I ended up solving this by building all circles using canvas. An svg map with d3 zoom, but with canvas circles. If you have a d3 element and you place one finger on the element and the other on the map and try to pinch zoom it will not work. Using canvas and pointer tracking solves this.

This is the finished map and project https://pixelsandplans.com/live/flow/